# Pyarrow error - AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'feather'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyarrow, feather

I used `conda install pyarrow` to install pyarrow in Spyder launched through Anaconda navigator. But I received the following error after I try to save a file in feather format.

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    pyarrow.feather.write_feather(df,"/Users/omg/Downloads/testFeather.ftr")
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'feather'**

The code is

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow

tempArr = np.reshape(np.zeros(10), (5,2))
tempArr += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(tempArr, columns=['a', 'b'])
pyarrow.feather.write_feather(df,"/Users/omg/Downloads/testFeather.ftr")
```

versions are: 
pyarrow.**version**
'0.11.1'
np.**version**
'1.18.1'

pd.**version**
'1.0.3'

Comment: Your `pyarrow` version is quite old, try updating to 0.17 (or at least 0.15+)

Comment: One thing is that conda, even use forge, will only find version up to 0.11. I forced to install 0.15. Perhaps conda should fix that too.

Comment: conda-forge has the recent pyarrow=0.17.1, if it isn't installed in your environment, you probably have another outdated package that references pyarrow=0.11.

Answer (score 2):

`feather` is a module inside `pyarrow`. This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyarrow import feather
import numpy as np

tempArr = np.reshape(np.zeros(10), (5,2))
tempArr += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(tempArr, columns=['a', 'b'])
feather.write_feather(df,"testFeather.ftr")
```